# Contrapositive of an informal conditional statement example with primes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, prime-numbers

Dear StackExchange community,

I'm teaching myself discrete mathematics via the book "Discrete Mathematics with Applications" by Susanna S. Epp. My foundation in maths is quite rocky plus English isn't my first language and so I came to trip over one of the exercises which wants me to state the contrapositive of an informal conditional statement which has an implicit universal statement in its conclusion:

If $n$ is prime, then $n$ is not divisible by any
prime number from $2$ through $\sqrt{n}$. (Assume
that $n$ is a fixed integer.)

By now I sure know that the contrapositive of a conditional statement is a conditional statement with the conclusion negated as the hypothesis and the hypothesis negated as the conclusion and that a negated universal statement is an existential statement with the predicate negated.

My solution would be:

If $n$ divisible by some prime number from $2$ through $\sqrt{n}$ then $n$ is not prime.

However, the real solution says:

If $n$ is divisible by some prime number between $1$ and $\sqrt{n}$ inclusive, then $n$ is not prime.

I just can't make sense of the range of prime numbers between $1$ and $\sqrt{n}$ inclusive to be the answer.

I would appreciate you dearly if you want to help me understand this.
Sorry for the wall of text, it's my first post here and I will try to adjust my future posts according to your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> state the contrapositive:
>
> If $n$ is prime, then $n$ is not divisible by any prime number from $2$ through $\sqrt{n}.$
>
> My solution:
>
> If $n$ divisible by some **prime number from $2$ through $\sqrt{n}$** then
> $n$ is not prime.
>
> However, the real solution:
>
> If $n$ is divisible by some **prime number between $1$ and $\sqrt{n}$
> inclusive**, then $n$ is not prime.

You're both correct, since, in ascending order, the list of primes starting from $1$ is identical to the list of primes starting from $2.$

Rephrasing that set of interest was an unnecessary distraction by the author.